# Использование системы пользователей WordPress в стороннем проекте

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

Необходимо реализовать доступ к стороннему проекту через систему пользователей WordPress. 
**Пример:** пользователь вводит данные от своего аккаунта в форму на стороннем сайте. После этого, в случае валидности данных, он получает доступ к функционалу сайта. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении копать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно по-разному.

Например, на WP сайте вызвать `wp_login_form()`, там есть параметр `redirect`. После успешной авторизации перекинуть на страницу стороннего проекта, адрес которой указан в `redirect`.

Можно на стороннем сайте отправить POST-запрос на WP-сайт. В обработчике вызвать `wp_authenticate()`, чтобы проверить имя и пароль, полученные по POST. Ответить с помощью `wp_send_json_success()` или `wp_send_json_error()`. На стороннем сайте обработать ответ должным образом.

Comment: Я прописал функцию для авторизации в functions.php (Вы  так советовали в одном ответе: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/646127/unity3d-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-wordpress-woocommerce/646152#646152)
Проблем несколько. Во-первых, выставил ссылку на главную страницу вордпресс в action у формы. Выводит success: false, хотя данные правильные. Во-вторых, функция срабатывает не только при редиректе с формы. 
Можете помочь? Заранее признателен.

Comment: Я немного погуглил. Проблема в пустых запросах при редиректе на главную страницу вордпресса, если редиректить, допустим, на wordpress/news - все работает. Странно.

Comment: Разобрался. В моем случае можно использовать внешний файл-обработчик, допустим, form.php. Подключаем в нем wp-load.php и wp_authenticate работает,  валидные данные признаются валидными,  все отлично.